# PHP mod_fcgi with fastcgi_finish_request();

Tags: php, fastcgi

I want to use the `fastcgi_finish_request()` function.

I have CPanel installed on my server and PHP and Apache are both configured through that. Since I cannot edit Apache or PHP configuration manually (because of CPanel), I used easyApache in WHM to build it in order to get fastcgi.

I saw an option caled Mod FCGID, so I enabled it.

After rebuilding PHP and Apache with that option enabled, I still get call to `undefined function` when calling the `fastcgi_finish_request` function.

Answer (score 13):

A little late, but good info for people. In my experience working with PHP 5.5.7.

PHP using mod_php (standard Apache):

```
ob_start();
header("Connection: close\r\n"); 
header('Content-Encoding: none\r\n');

// your code here

$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: ". $size . "\r\n"); 
// send info immediately and close connection
ob_end_flush();
flush();

// run other process without the client attached.
```

For PHP using FastCGI and PHP_FPM:

```
// your code here

fastcgi_finish_request();

// run other process without the client attached.
```

Note that for us, after `fastcgi_finish_request()` was executed, `log_error` no longer worked. I assume it is because the connection to Apache is also severed and it cannot communicate with FastCGI to log the error.

Comment: Tried the `Content-Length` trick with Apache, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This code doesn't return a confirmation to the browser until the script/process has been fully executed. So what's the difference between your recommendation and simply using:  ignore_user_abort(true); set_time_limit(0); ?

Answer (score 8):

`fastcgi_finish_request` is **PHP-FPM** SAPI specific function, unavailable in standard php-fcgi binary (used by Apache [mod_fcgid, mod_fastcgi], nginx, lighttpd etc).

Comment: is there an equivilent to that for mod_fcgi?

Comment: If you are limited to cpanel functionality I doubt there is anything you can do. If you are able to compile and add extension to php, http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php can be used to schedule jobs and finish request