# php -prevent curl_setopt stop running the page

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm using curl for sending sms in my script. sometimes the sms server is not responding and it'll cause the script to run anymore and stop the page right away .

this is my code:

```
$url = "myserver/services.jspd";
    $mobile = substr($tel, 1);
    $rcpt_nm = array($mobile);


    $param = array(
        'uname' => 'xxxxx',
        'pass' => '1111',
        'from' => '+xxxxxx'
        'message' => $body,
        'to' => json_encode($rcpt_nm),
        'op' => 'send');

    $handler = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
    curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response2 = curl_exec($handler);

    $response2 = json_decode($response2);
```

this is the sending sms code in the middle of my main page.

how can I handle this situation , I don't want to stop running the page and I want to allow the page to continue loading

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024821/php-curl-required-only-to-send-and-not-wait-for-response