# How to forcing set header content length?

Tags: php

I have a big PHP file, It takes a long time to execute.
so I want to set Content-Length = 26. for don't wait until the end.
But the problem is The server always set 'Content-Length' as actually Length.
How can I forcing Content-Length?

```php
header('Connection: close');
header('Cache-control: no-store');
// set Content-Length for just 26
header('Content-Length: 26');
echo 'Received and Processing...';
flush();ob_flush();


//// some codes...
//// some codes...
//// some codes...

echo 'end!';
```

I try on Local server the output: Received and Processing...

but in my website server, the output is:
Received and Processing...end!

how can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood what you are saying in your question and subsequent comments, you want the server to acknowledge the action sooner and not wait for the processing to complete.

Tinkering with http headers is not the right way to do this. Assuming that you are not interested in any new information which might arise during processing, then there are various ways to achieve this, but you need to dissociate execution of the processing from the navigation thread.

If you trigger a second PHP process (either using the first PHP process to make an http request or from JavaScript at the browser) and set a timeout on that operation, and begin the second script with `ignore_user_abort(true)` then you will have achieved that. There are [other solutions](http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html).

But if the delay is due to bandwidth limits you have no choice but to wait.

Comment: yes, this is what I want!
But how can I send POST request to longThing.php by this way?

Comment: After the file is on the server you use a separate process to do the thing which takes a long time. There is nothing you can do to speed up the process of transferring the file. You can distrct from this by halding the upload via ajax or in an iframe which changing stuff elsewhere o the page.

Comment: I found a solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024821/php-curl-required-only-to-send-and-not-wait-for-response/8057969

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP `Content-Length` header is not a timeout. It tells the receiver of an HTTP message how many bytes the body of the message contains so that the receiver knows when to stop reading more bytes from the connection. If the `Content-Length` header contains a wrong value, things will break. You should **never** have to set that header manually.

To limit execution time of a PHP script, the function [`set_time_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and the global config variable [`max_execution_time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) seem to be your options.

Comment: I do't want to limit execution time. I want to set 'Content-Length' but the server set it as actually length

Comment: @BaselKhatib in your question you said you don't want to wait for the file to finish executing, I must've misunderstood.

In any event, you should never set the Content-Type header yourself, as that **will** cause problems at the receiver, if not before.